# For loop in python for a SAS Macro SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to convert a SAS macro SQL to equivalent python code.My SAS macro SQL is

```
proc sql;
select count(distinct fx) into :fx_count from processing_wgt;
select min(fx) into :fx_start from processing_wgt;
quit;

%do i=1 %to &fx_count.;

data _fx_processing_wgt;
set processing_wgt;
where fx=&fx_start.+&i.-1;
run;
data _fx_weights;
set gm_weights;
where fx=&fx_start.+&i.-1;
run;
```

My python code is given below:

```
fx_count = processing_wgt.fx.nunique()
print(fx_count)

fx_start=processing_wgt['fx'].min()
print(fw_start)
```

But I am unable to write the for loop for the condition mentioned above.I am new in python,I will be needing help how to do this.

Comment: So to check - do you have `processing_wgt` as an actual Pandas DF? (eg: from using `pandas.read_sas` or something else?)

Comment: also... where does the `gm_weights` dataset come into this... ?

Comment: processing_wgt and gm_weights they both are pandas DF and gm_weights is a different dataset

Comment: Umm... could you describe in just plain language what you're trying to achieve... your datasteps and your attempted Python code don't seem to add up (that or I've not had enough coffee yet!)

Comment: Why are you trying to split the dataset (dataframes) into smaller data frames?  Why not just group the original data by the FX variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
    fx_count = processing_wgt.fx.nunique()
    fx_start=processing_wgt['fx'].min()
    for i in range(1,fx_count+1):
        _fx_processing_wgt = processing_wgt[processing_wgt.fx.eq(fx_start+i-1)]
        _fx_weights= gm_weights[gm_weights.fx.eq(fx_start+i-1)
```

Comment: assuming that processing_wgt and gm_weights read as pandas dataframe from the source locations.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**